# Can not reach method inside TPL Task from NUnit

Tags: .net-core, nunit, task-parallel-library

I have a a `class` that has a  long running `Task` field.For some reason when i am debugging with `NUnit` i can not enter the method that is run inside the  `Task` with the debugger and see what happens.

```
class WorkerTests {

        class Loop {
            public Task innerLoop;
            public void Run(CancellationToken token) {
                this.innerLoop = Task.Run(LoopAsync, token); //wont enter in LoopAsync
            }
            private async Task LoopAsync() {
                while (true) {   //i want to reach here
                    Debug.WriteLine("in loop");
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }
            }
        }
        [TestCase]
        public async Task TestLoop() {
            CancellationTokenSource src = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Loop loop = new Loop();
            loop.Run(src.Token);
            await loop.innerLoop;
        }
}
```

How can i reach with the debugger inside the `LoopAsync` method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not enter with the debugger in the `Task` because in my case the method was in another `DLL`( a windows forms).This `DLL` had no debugging symbols loaded.
I solved it with `Project->Properties->Build->Advanced->Debugging Information set to Full`